# F# - Extract parameter from Expr

Tags: f#

My questions will no end take...

I've the function:

```
let hasMany (expr:Expr<'a -> seq<'b>>)
```

now I want to extract the `seq<'b>` from the `Expr` since I need to cast it to an `ICollection<'b>` and wrap it back into a new `Expr` - Why not just make it take an `Expr` that takes an `ICollection<'b>` in the first place you may ask - simple enough the user would need to first cast the `seq<'b>` to an `ICollection<'b>`, which I'm trying to avoid since I'm creating a library thats going to be used by others than me, and I want it to be easy and clean.

Short: How do I extract the `seq<'b>`from the `Expr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense to me.  Given your types, there is no `seq<'b>` in `expr` - `expr` is an expression wrapping a *function* which *returns* a `seq<'b>`.  For instance, with the signature you've got, it would be valid to call

```
hasMany <@ id @>
```

since `id` can be given the type `'b seq -> 'b seq`.  However, clearly `<@ id @>` doesn't contain a `seq<'b>`!

If what you're asking is to convert your `Expr<'a -> seq<'b>>` into an `Expr<'a -> ICollection<'b>>`, then try this:

```
let hasMany (expr : Expr<'a -> 'b seq>) =
    <@ fun x -> (%expr) x :?> ICollection<'b> @>
```