# F# - Reconstruct Expression Tree

Tags: f#

Alright... this question is more or less related to one I've asked earlier today ([F# - "Not a valid property expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776307/f-not-a-valid-property-expression)), which @Tomas Petricek answer perfectly - however it seems my lack of knowledge and the DLR, requires me to ask once again (been trying for quite a while to mix something up without luck at all).

I'm having this function (stolen from the example Tomas gave in the previous thread):

```
let hasSeq (e:Expr<'a -> seq<'b>>) =
  match e with
  | Patterns.Lambda(v, Patterns.PropertyGet(Some instance, propInfo, [])) ->
      printfn "Get property %s of %A" propInfo.Name instance
      // TODO: Use 'Expr.Lambda' & 'Expr.PropGet' to construct
      // an expression tree in the expected format
  | _ -> failwith "Not a lambda!"
```

How would I reconstruct the expression tree with `Expr.Lambda` and `Expr.PropGet`? - I need to make the `seq<'b>` to `ICollection<'b>` instead, so that the expression in the end is like: `'a -> ICollection<'b>`

Comment: You should also add that you don't want to get the same quotation as the result of reconstruction. You need a different one (as pointed out in your earlier question that is also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759332/f-extract-parameter-from-expr).

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you've already decomposed quotation, then maybe you can create required expression tree by yourself without `ToLinqExpression` from PowerPack?

```
type A = 
    member this.Values : int[] = failwith "" 

open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

type F<'T, 'R> = System.Func<'T, 'R>
type E = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression
type IC<'T> = System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<'T> 

let toLinqPropGet (e : Expr<'T -> #seq<'R>>) = 
    match e with
    | Patterns.Lambda(_, Patterns.PropertyGet(Some _, pi, [])) 
          when typeof<IC<'R>>.IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType) ->
        let p = E.Parameter(typeof<'T>)
        let propGet = E.Property(p :> E, pi)
        E.Lambda<F<'T, IC<'R>>>(propGet, p) :> E
    | _ -> failwith "PropGet expected"

let r = toLinqPropGet <@ fun (x : A) -> x.Values @>        
printfn "%A" r
```

Comment: @desco, forgive my stupidness - the toLinqPropGet will return `E` and what I need is `Expr<'a -> ICollection<'b>>`, can I achieve that somehow with your code?

Comment: @desco: This is a part of a longer series of questions by the OP. I suggested using `ToLinqExpression` earlier. If I understand him correctly, he wants to build a different quotation tree (so I suggested transforming the quotation and then transforming that to LINQ expression trees). However, I'm not quite sure what quotation he wants to get.

Comment: @Tomas, I want to rebuild the expression so that I dont need to cast `Expr<'a -> seq<'b>>` in order to transform it to `Expr<'a -> ICollection<'b>>`, because that would mess up the `ToLinq` function since `UnboxGeneric` will be added when casted. So in short: I need to rebuild the expression and avoid including the `UnboxGeneric` (not sure whether that made any sense... I'm having a hard time to explain).

Comment: @ebb That's not possible. See my answer.

Comment: (Or maybe I recommended using `ToLinqExpression` in some other question - getting a bit confused!)

Comment: @desco, it seems like the code you've suggested would throw an exception if I pass in a `seq<'b>` instead of `int[]`... Atleast it jumps to the `failwith` clause. Also if I remove then `when` at the first match pattern, then it throws an exception on the line where `propGet` is declared, that `seq<'b>` cant be casted...

Comment: If your property has type seq<_> then, as @Tomas already suggested, you can use pair of properties: one for client code (with type seq<_>), another - for EF (with ICollection<_>).

Comment: @desco, I'm lost... The client code would then that have to call the EF method which requires a `System.Expression<Func<'T, ICollection<R>>`, and how would you make that one up in the client code? As I said in my previous comment then I cant use the function you've suggested... Anyway, I might be blind and therefore haven't seen the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work.

You want to build a quotation of type `Entity -> ICollection<Something>` and you have a quotation of type `Entity -> seq<Something>`. However, entity framework only supports simple lambda functions that get some property (e.g. `x => x.SomeProperty`).

If your `Entity` has only a property `Foo` of type `seq<Something>`, then there is no way you could build a quotation with the required structure (lambda that just gets a property) and of the required type (`Entity -> ICollection<Something>`), because the type of the property doesn't match!

What I suggested earlier is to change the entity to also have a property `FooInternal` of the right type (`ICollection<Something>`). Then you could build a quotation `x => x.FooInternal`, which would work fine with entity framework.

Perhaps you could give more details about what you're actually trying to achieve? We can try to help with technical details, but it seems that you may need to adjust your design a bit (to actually work with the `ICollection` type as required by EF).

Comment: @Tomas Petricek, The actually reason for not using `Expr<'a -> ICollection<'b>>` as parameter instead of `Expr<'a -> seq<'b>>` is that I'm trying to make it possible for users to use sequences instead of ICollections, since ICollections isnt very... how should I explain it.. well most people who use f# arent gonna use ICollections at any point, and therefore I thought it would be a good idea to make up functions that took expressions with `seq<'b>`, `'b list` and `array<'b>`, which would make the process more "natural" for the user... But it seems to be a bit harder than I thought.

Comment: @ebb I see your motivation, using sequences would be nicer. However, Entity Framework obviously requires using `ICollection` and there is not much you could do about that. Unless you wanted to have both `Foo : seq<T>` (for user) and `FooInternal : ICollection<T>` (for EF methods). Then you could build expression tree that uses the other property.

Comment: @Tomas Petricek, Oh god... I would wish I knew this stuff a bit more so I didnt had to ask all the time, but here it goes: How would you build an expression tree that uses another property?

Comment: @ebb Find the property using `propInfo` and .NET reflection and then write something like `Expr.Lambda(v, Expr.PropertyGet(instance, newlyFoundPropInfo))`

Comment: @ebb Alternatively, you can do what @desco suggests in his answer (to use standard .NET methods that construct C# expression tree directly - there should be plenty of information about that on the internet).

Comment: @Tomas Petricek, After a few hours of reading some of the DLR documents through, and trying various things then I've ended up with the conclusion that you simply cant do as in the example @desco has given, since it will throw an exception when using `seq<'b>` at the `E.Lambda<F<'T, IC<'R>>>(propGet, p)`: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.String]'.. So I think I'm pretty much stuck with using `ICollection<'a>` for the user.